# Factoring Polynomial over GF(8)

Tags: finite-fields, factoring

It is known that polynomial over GF(2) $x^6+x+1$=$g_1(x)*g_2(x)*g_3(x)$, where $g_i$ is irreducible over GF(8) and deg $g_i(x)$=2. What is the most optimal way to find those polynomials?

Comment: I think trying all candidates is not so bad.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^6+x+1$ then $\alpha\in GF(64)$ and the factors are
$$g_1(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^8), g_2(x)=(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^{16}), g_3(x)=(x-\alpha^4)(x-\alpha^{32}).$$ But you want the coefficients of these written as elements of $GF(8)$. How is $GF(8)$ described to you?